# Remove names that contain another in a list

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I have a file with `"Name|Number"` in each line and I wish to remove the lines with names that contain another name in the list.
For example, if there is `"PEDRO|3" , "PEDROFILHO|5" , "PEDROPHELIS|1" in the file, i wish to remove the lines  "PEDROFILHO|5" , "PEDROPHELIS|1".`

The list has 1.8 million lines, I made it like this but its too slow :

```
List<string> names = File.ReadAllLines("firstNames.txt").ToList();
List<string> result = File.ReadAllLines("firstNames.txt").ToList();

foreach (string name in names)
{
    string tempName = name.Split('|')[0];
    List<string> temp = names.Where(t => t.Contains(tempName)).ToList();
    foreach (string str in temp)
    {
        if (str.Equals(name))
        {
            continue;
        }
        result.Remove(str);
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines("result.txt",result);
```

Does anyone know a faster way? Or how to improve the speed?

Comment: Would you also like to remove `"DELPEDRO|5"`, or are you looking only for prefix matches?

Comment: That would also be removed, any name that contains another name in the list would be removed.

Comment: Prefix matching can be done tremendously faster using something like a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or even just sorting the list and doing a binary search. Depending on the number of eliminations, it might be faster to get all of the prefix matches eliminated first, followed by a "contains" check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for matches everywhere in the word, you will end up with O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. You can improve implementation a bit to avoid string deletion inside a list, which is an O(n) operation in itself:

```
var toDelete = new HashSet<string>();
var names = File.ReadAllLines("firstNames.txt");
foreach (string name in names) {
    var tempName = name.Split('|')[0];
    toDelete.UnionWith(
        // Length constraint removes self-matches
        names.Where(t => t.Length > name.Length && t.Contains(tempName))
    );
}
File.WriteAllLines("result.txt", names.Where(name => !toDelete.Contains(name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but I don't know if it's quicker. I haven't tested on millions of lines. Remove the tolower if the names are in the same case.

```
        List<string> names = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\File.txt").ToList();

        var result = names.Where(w => !names.Any(a=> w.Split('|')[0].Length> a.Split('|')[0].Length  &&  w.Split('|')[0].ToLower().Contains(a.Split('|')[0].ToLower())));

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\result.txt", result);
```

test file had

Rob|1
Robbie|2
Bert|3
Robert|4
Jan|5
John|6
Janice|7
Carol|8
Carolyne|9
Geoff|10
Geoffrey|11

Result had

Rob|1
Bert|3
Jan|5
John|6
Carol|8
Geoff|10

Comment: John and Bert should have been returned in this case

Comment: Absolutely agree, my eagerness to help was unhelpful.

Comment: I know it's already answered but I don't get out much and I was curious about speed. bug corrected